# Android, start new activity using same activity class, is this possible?

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to create an app with navigation, wiyh navigation flow like this

**ListView Activity** -> **Detail Activity** (item 1) -> **Detail Activity** (item 2)-> **Detail Activity**  (item 3) -> ... and so on

is this posible? how to achive this?

---

Edited

Sorry for being not clear,

Lets say i have activity with ListView, then when i tap one item, it will start new activity which contain detail information of selected item, and from those activity, there are next / previous button, and when i tap it, it will start new activity using same class and layout, but with information of next or previous item of ListView previously selected item.

Oh and also I need that user can return to previous screen on each backkey, so when user tap back key the activity will go like this

**Detail Activity**  (item 3) (finish) -> **Detail Activity** (item 2) (finish) -> **Detail Activity** (item 1) (finish) -> **ListView Activity**

Comment: Didn't get your question. What are you trying to achieve? Is these are subactivity of detailactivity or what?

Comment: Edited, tell me if you need more info.

Comment: No i want to ask, is this even possible?, how to do this? how i write the activity declaration in AndroidManifest? do i just need to write one activity declaration? and how to send next / previous item of selected list view item, to the next activity using intent?

something like that

Comment: for that you can use View Flipper and also fragment which will be replaced with each other.

Comment: U will need to create your layout again and again in the same activity through java code. On click of the next call mainlayout.removeallviews() and the add new view or layout to it.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Did you mean ViewPager?

Comment: No its something different from ViewPager

Comment: yes it is possible Activity call itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way

Yes this is possible to call Activity call it self, because Every activity is different process in android.

Activity stack will maintain by Android Don't worry about that.

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

        // call DetailAcitvity

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("item", "item1");
            startActivity(intent);



    }

    public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

        // Calling itself 

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("item", "item2");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```